# Lines and number of transfers in a transit network using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

How can I build a transit network in igraph so it would take into account the lines and the number of transfers between them? 
I’d like to be able to define lines. So, for instance, if I calculate the shortest paths between two vertices (stations) I’d like to know the number of transfers between lines needed in that path.

For example, let's assume 3 metro lines, and I calculate the shortest path between A and E, I obtain: A, E and D, which is correct. However I'd like to know somehow that despite being the shortest path, a transfer from line 2 to line 3 is needed in the node E, whereas the path A, B, C, D is direct. How can I define those lines in igraph and know when transfer between lines happen?

Line 1: A, B, C, D
Line 2: A, E
Line 3: E, D

```
m  <-  rbind(c("A", "B"),
         c("B", "C"),
         c("C", "D"),
         c("A", "E"),
         c("E", "D"))
g <- graph.data.frame(m, directed=FALSE)
sp <- get.shortest.paths(g, from="A", to="D") 
V(g)[sp$vpath[[1]]]
### Result in the console: 
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A" "E" "D"
```

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific than this. In particular, include some data and code.

Comment: I included a basic example and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key ingredients that are missing from your code yet. First, the dataset does not contain which connections belong to which lines, so you have to provide that information first. The easiest is probably by adding annotations to the edges in the data frame you construct the graph from:

```
> connections <- data.frame(source=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "E"), target=c("B", "C", "D", "E", "D"), line=c("red", "red", "red", "green", "yellow"))
```

Then you can find the shortest path between two stations using `get.shortest.paths`, but you will need not only the *vertices* along each route but also the *edges* because a transfer between two lines will happen when two consecutive edges do not belong to the same line:

```
> g <- graph.data.frame(connections, directed=F)
> sp <- get.shortest.paths(g, from="A", to="D", output="both")
> V(g)[sp$vpath[[1]]]
Vertex sequence:
[1] "A" "E" "D"
> E(g)[sp$epath[[1]]]
Edge sequence:

[4] E -- A
[5] D -- E
> lines <- E(g)[sp$epath[[1]]]$line
> num.transfers <- sum(head(lines,-1) != tail(lines,-1))
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you Tamás. Additionally, is there any way to calculate the shortest path adding this transfer constraint? Following this example, find the shortest path between A and D with less than 1 transfer.

Comment: Not directly with `get.shortest.paths`. Route planners usually handle this by searching for shortest paths in the line graph of the original graph, where every edge of the original graph becomes a vertex in the line graph, and every path of length 2 in the original graph becomes an edge in the line graph. You can then assign weights to the edges in the line graph such that edges representing transfers get a higher weight; the shortest paths will then tend to use edges with low weights, i.e. without transfers.

Comment: FWIW, igraph has a `line.graph` function which creates the line graph for you, but you are on your own from then on.